# How to specify SHA2 in a mysql data file using phpmyadmin 5.2.0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sha2

When specifying a password in a data field in phpmyadmin for including in a table, the function dropdown allows SHA1 to be selected. There is no SHA2 functionality. I am using version 5.2.0 on XAMPP in my development environment.

Is there a workaround for doing this in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

It seems support for using the SHA2 functions isn't yet present in phpMyAdmin itself, but I've opened a feature request for it here https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17760